# How to replace "{ with { in string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

Can anyone tell me how to replace `"{` with `{` using JavaScript?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
string.replace(/\"\{/g, "{");
```

Comment: Your example should work by all means.

Comment: I tested it just in case and it works for me

Comment: You've tagged your question with JSON. Are you sure you don't just want `JSON.parse()`?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is fine. Don't forget that strings are immutable in javascript. The replace function doesn't change the receiver string but builds a new one.

So you must do

```
string = string.replace(/\"\{/g, "{");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you were using this directly on `string` you should use it on an instance of string. Not on string type.

(I know it sounds too trivial, but otherwise this code should have worked. :) )

```
var stringTypeVariable = 'some string "{ with target pattern';
var replacedVariable = stringTypeVariable.replace(/\"\{/g, "{");
```